# unable to change wlan0 mac address on raspberry pi 2

Tags: wifi, wireless

I'm trying to change mac (hardware) address of my `wlan0`, however for whatever reason I'm unable to do so:

```
# ifconfig wlan0 down
# ifconfig wlan0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Device or resource busy - you may need to down the interface
```

I tried `macchanger` also, but I got `command not found`.

Comment: Have you done if ifdown and then ifup as the message suggests?

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes, my first line before that is `ifconfig wlan0 down`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` with a `.conf` extension that has this line:

```
options 8192cu rtw_initmac="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
```

Do `modinfo 8192cu` to see all the params.

Comment: FWIW when I had single quotes around the MAC address it put some "random" MAC address. The address was set correctly when I removed them. I'm running Wheezy on kernel 4.1.19+

Answer (score 2):

Ran via an ssh session over ethernet.

`sudo service ifplugd stop
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`

then change the MAC address

`ifconfig wlan0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

make sure you start the service again

`sudo service ifplugd start`

'ifconfig'

will now show the new MAC address (if your hardware and drivers support it)

If you get 
`SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address`
then the substitute MAC address is not valid.

Comment: "...via an `ssh` session over Ethernet..." - useful point folks!  If you tweak the details of the connection you are using to access the RPi (or any other networked device) you can get stuck if some of the details change part way through and disconnect you before you can complete them... 8-)

Answer (score 2):

Some drivers don't allow the change.
In particular, rtl8192cu.ko allows the change, but 8192cu.ko (although fixes other bugs present in 8192cu.ko) does not. See [this](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/issues/38).